# Export DataGrid Data to PDF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, export, sql-server-express

I know that there are a few similar questions and I googled a lot but the code samples are all over using objects.
In my WPF-application, I don´t have objects(like book, store etc.), I just fill a datagrid with data from SQLExpress.

What is the best way to export this data to pdf/csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say export to pdf/csv - but they're both very different topics for discussion. If by using '/' you mean 'or', well then google something like "c# write text file". The more difficult one would be writing to pdf - you'll need a third party library. I won't ellaborate any further because the quality of your question doesn't warrant it.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the best outlook when it comes to software development to be honest. Most of the fun I have comes from the challenge of having to achieve the difficult things, if you accept less at the first obstacle you'll have software that is not of top quality and it won't be as beneficial with regards to you growing as a developer. I didn't mean that you should opt for csv output - I meant that your question was not clear enough for me to decide on which to help you with - both outputs require very different code. Either way, good luck.